# Mosaic 70 rasters to a new raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, mosaic, combine

[image]

I have 80 rasters that I want to combine with Mosaic to new raster.

1. Is the order of adding inputs important ?
2. Is there any quicker way to add all those rasters ?

Comment: Yes, the order is important but why are you mosaicing? If you have a standard or advanced license you can create a mosaic dataset which acts like a raster but is made of your input tiles https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000003p000000. If you've only got a basic license there is a GDAL utility GDALBuildVRT that can build a virtual raster from your tiles (an XML file) - these are a bit slower to use than a mosaic dataset in ArcGIS but they still work and would allow you to see the end result before committing to it if you export to a new raster.

Comment: Try create mosaic dataset. Export image from it using catalog.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, the order is not important - they will be placed according to their spatial reference.
Yes, ArcMap is a bit annoying in the sense that you have to click on each raster name to add it to the list. In such case, you can quickly open QGIS (it's free and fast) and mosaic your rasters there: add them to view -> "processing" menu -> click "toolbox" -> in toolbox pane, under GDAL select "Raster miscellaneous" -> click "Merge"-> under "Input layers" choose "select all" -> run the merge and enjoy. In total it will be about 8 clicks, not 80 ;)

Comment: You can drag drop 100s of raster from w.explorer.